# Scala : Trying to generalize a method using generic types

Tags: scala, playframework, implicit-conversion

So, I have this method (in play framework/scala):

```
def toHttpResponse(entity: Option[Foo]) = {
   case Ok =>
     Ok(Json.toJson(entity))

    ...

}

def toHttpResponse(entity: Option[Bar]): = {
   case Ok =>
     Ok(Json.toJson(entity))

    ...
}
```

I also have these implicits in scope:

```
implicit val fooFormat = Json.format[Foo]
implicit val barFormat = Json.format[Bar]
```

So, I thought I would refactor and create a common method, like so:

```
def toHttpResponse[T](entity: T) = {
   case Ok =>
     Ok(Json.toJson(entity))

    ...
}
```

and ...now I'm getting these errors, even when the above implicits are in scope:

```
No Json serializer found for type T. Try to implement an implicit Writes or Format for this type.
```

What am I missing? I know its something to do with these implicits! Pointers appreciated. Thanks

Updated:
Answer
This suggestion by [Luis Miguel Mejía Suárez] worked like a charm:

```
def toHttpResponse[T : Writes]() = {
   ...
}
```

Comment: I do not know nothing about **Play**. But usually this problems are fixed by adding either a **Context Bound** or the **implicit parameter** _(which are equivalent)_. So something like `def toHttpResponse[T : Writes](...)` should work.

Comment: Note that context bound seems to be deprecated in Scala 2.13, as part of implicit refactoring

Comment: @cchantep do you have any source for that? I haven't heard of that before. Also I am 90% sure I have some `2.13` code using **Context Bounds** without any warning.

Comment: Try enabling warning

Comment: @cchantep I just tested creating a simple `Show` **typeclass** on a project where I have the `sbt-tpolecat` plugin _(that would enable all warnings)_ + Scala `2.13`. And I did not see any warning by using it as a context bound.

Answer (score 2):

A `Writes` instance must be resolved from the implicit scope:

```
def toHttpResponse[T](entity: T)(implicit w: Writes[T]) = {
   case Ok =>
     Ok(Json.toJson(entity))

    ...
}
```